# Qt/C++: What's the best way to call a method asynchronously in Qt event loop without having to write its name as string?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, asynchronous, qt5

The normal way is with `invokeMethod`:

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this, "methodName", Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

which works fine, except that I don't want to write methods in strings. Like ever. Why? Because this is a refactoring nightmare. Imagine having to change a method name for some reason. The software will malfunction and I'll have to notice in stderr that the method doesn't exist.

#### My solution?

I use QTimer. Like this:

```
QTimer::singleShot(0, this, &ClassName::methodName);
```

which seems to work fine. What I like about this is that you can replace the `&ClassName::methodName` part with a lambda/bind and it'll still be bound to the correct object (in case I need to use it with QThread) with the expected variable referencing we understand in standard C++:

```
QTimer::singleShot(0, threadObject, [this, param1, &param2](){ this->methodName(param1, param2); });
```

#### Better solutions exist?

But... I'm hoping there's a better way to do this because someone reading my code will not understand why I'm using a QTimer here... so I gotta comment everything.

Is there a better way to do this that's compatible with versions of Qt down to 5.9 or 5.7? What's the best solution you know?

Comment: The notice will go to stderr, not stdout.

Comment: are you sure the call is not immediate and then synchronous when the timer delay is 0, because of optimization ?

Comment: @bruno I'm sure. Because I use this for multithreading as well. If you move the QObject to another thread, it'll execute it on that thread.

Comment: Based on your final comments in the post it sounds as if your main concern is actually readability on the part of others? If so, why not just wrap up the lambda based solution into a short function named e.g. `run_task_on_objects_thread` or similar?

Comment: @G.M. Totally right. That's basically what occurred to me after posting the question :D

Answer (score 1):

Since Qt 5.10 there are [functor-based overloads of `QMetaObject::invokeMethod`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#invokeMethod-4).

This means that you can ditch the string-based approach and use the modern way of calling methods with `invokeMethod` too.

Comment: Too modern. Unfortunately, I have to support 5.9 still at least (and I think even 5.7 for Ubuntu 16). Anyway, for the sake of having a complete answer, can you please write examples (that work for you) in your answer?

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist I rarely need such an indirection, so I can't think of a nice example. If you have some code where `QTimer::singleShot` works for you, I can just alter it to use `QMetaObject::invokeMethod` instead (that would be a trivial edit though, so not sure if it'd be useful).

Answer (score 0):

Actually `QTimer` is not an asynchronous way to solve your problem. It pushes your method onto the stack to call your method when the currently executing method exits.

I think that the better solution is to use [QtConcurrent run](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrentrun.html). It will execute your method in async way.

It is simple to use it:

```cpp
QtConcurrent::run(&myFunc); // some function
QtConcurrent::run(this, &MyClass::method); // for class method
QtConcurrent::run(this, &MyClass::methodWithParams, param1, param2); // for class method with params
```

Also, you should include **concurrent** to your `.qmake` file like this:

```
...
QT += concurrent
...
```

If you need a result of function, you can use [QFuture](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfuture.html) class.

Comment: I'm sorry, there might be a misunderstanding. Asynchronous doesn't mean in another thread. It means in the Qt event loop (which may or may not be in another thread). Is this what you mean? As far as I understand, QtConcurrent is strictly for multithreading.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, my mistake. It actually calls the method on a different thread. I thought that you need to execute this method while the current method is running. Then, as far as I know, `invokeMethod()` will be the best solution. And in your case, if you don't want use strings, you can just create another signal-slot connection and emit signal when you need to call your method.

Comment: It's too messy to create another signal/slot for every single async call... I tried that solution, and not only it's too much bloat, but for multithreading, if one is not careful, things can be called multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

It's not much different from what you're already doing, but I've done it by connecting to the destruction of a QObject instead of using a QTimer.

```
template <typename Func>
void MyClass::runLater(Func &&func)
{
    QObject toBeDestroyed;
    QObject::connect(&toBeDestroyed, &QObject::destroyed, this, func, Qt::QueuedConnection);
}
```

And then I can call it with a lambda:

```
void doSomething(const QString &text, int num)
{
    runLater([text, num]() { qDebug() << text << num; });
}
```